Short story about a city enclosed in an electromagnetic field
The story seems to take place during the cold war. Inhabitants of the city (maybe New York) are isolated by a field surrounding the city. Noone is able to deduce what is causing it. It is told from the point of view of the man co-opted to solve the problem. He is an expert in harmonics.

Perhaps "The Box" by James Blish: https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v34n01_1949-04/page/n129/mode/2up

Blish developed this concept into the "spindizzy", featured in his Cities In Flight series. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65316/116908

"The Box", a short story by James Blish which was also the answer to this old question; first published in Thrilling Wonder Stories, April 1949, available at the Internet Archive. You may have read it in one of these compilations.
The city trapped in "The Box" is indeed New York:

"It's like this," Frank Schafer said, kneading a chunk of art gum rapidly. "This dome went up last night. It lets in a little light, and a few of the strongest outside radio stations near by. But that's all—or anyhow, all that we've been able to establish so far. It's a perfect dome, over the whole island and parts of the other boroughs and New Jersey. It doesn't penetrate the ground or the water, but the only really big water frontage is way out in the harbor—so that lets out much chance of everybody swimming under it like that man from the Miss New York."

The viewpoint character is Jake Meister, a "resonance engineer":

Schafer grinned nastily. "Sure, Jake! This barrier obviously doesn't act specifically on nuclear reactions; it stops almost everything. Almost everyone here is a nuclear man, as useless for this problem as a set of cooky-cutters. Every fact we've gotten so far shows this thing to be an immense and infinitely complicated form of cavity-resonance—and you're the only resonance engineer inside it."

Stuff about harmonics:

Resonance, of course. The upper harmonics were echoes. Yet a simple primary tone in a well-known frequency range couldn't produce The Box by itself; it was the harmonics that made the difference—and the harmonics couldn't appear without the existence of some chamber like The Box. Along this line of reasoning, The Box was a pre-condition of its own existence.

The Box is the result of enemy action. The enemy is not identified in the story, but it was published in 1949, early in the Cold War, so there are obvious suspects.

The colonel looked at the landlord. "Mr. Dean," he said quietly, "you seem to think The Box was created to annoy you personally. The Army hasn't the technical knowledge to destroy it, but it has sense enough to realize that more than just New York is under attack here. The enemy, whoever he may be, thinks his screen uncrackable otherwise he wouldn't have given us this chance to work on it by boxing in one city alone. If The Box is not down in, say, eight days, he'll know that New York failed and died—and every city in the country will be bombed to slag the next morning."


I've seen quite a few stories - and films - about cities trapped inside force fields.

@StanleyWebb In particular, Stephen King wrote a novel called "Under The Dome" that is a riff on this theme. It was aliens.

@wastrel. I've read it. Good.

@StanleyWebb The original story on that theme is "The Lanson Screen" (1936) by Arthur Leo Zagat: https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v08n03_1936-12/page/n41/mode/2up
